# Keep Certificates in Central Location

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I used this screen in Visual Studio 2017 to set the certificate for my project.

[image: Signing Screen]

But it decided to copy the certificate into the project:

[image: Solution Shows Certificate]

What can do to prevent VS from copying my certificate into the source code?

I don't want to accidentally check it in.  As a workaround, I am going to add it to the .gitignore file, but I would rather it be completely outside of the source.

[EDIT] In response to @RodrigoM's keen observation about certificate is safe because it has the password: That is true.  The system prompted me for the password.  Now I am concerned where the password is stored ;).  So now I have an additional question:

Where is the password stored that I entered when I added my certificate to the solution?

Comment: I will point out that the .pfx file contains the private key, not just a certificate, and you are thus quite right to be concerned.

Comment: However If the pfx has a pasphrase it would be secure. Is this cert for signing?

Answer (score -1):

Adding certificate file to .gitignore is enough to be completely sure, that accidental check-in will never happen. Consider default .gitignore [file for Visual Studio](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore), it contains rule by .pfx extension (line 219). You can set up `Build Action` to `None` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Do not copy`, just in case.

Another option that you have is adding certificate file as link (Project => Add => Existing Item => Add as Link). So you will see the certificate in your Solution Explorer, but the actual file will be located in some directory on your machine, far away from folder with git checkout.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have a personal rule that if I vote down, I also add a comment.  Here is why I voted you down: It is pretty easy to accidentally check in files.  Saying "completely sure" is not really true.  I could easily create a new project and forget to add *.pfx to the .gitignore, or I could .zip this project up and send it to someone forgetting to drop the .pfx.  Also, use "Add as Link" is not an option of the screen I used to add the certificate, so it is not an option.  You are new to stack, don't let one downvote discourage you.  It is a great system.

Comment: Sorry for precipitate answer, and thank you for clarification. I don't know any workarounds in these circumstances. VS can't prevent you to zip your files and send it somewhere or somehow mark the particular file as 'gitignore everywhere'. It is user's responsibility, I suppose.